# AWS Lambda Application Structure

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml

I am using the AWS Lambda Application service to migrate a bot that has different commands. I want to create separate lambdas functions for each command so that one lambda function doesn't make another grow larger. I tried creating a single lambda application with two lambda functions, but the size of one lambda function is tied to the other in the project. Is there a way to sandbox the two lambda functions from each other inside one AWS Lambda Application or should I create a separate AWS Lambda Application for each lambda function?

This is how I created the application. First I opened the AWS console and went to the Lambda page. Then Applications > Create application > Author from scratch

Then I updated the template.yml Resources as follows

```
Resources:
  # Each Lambda function is defined by properties:
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction

  # Routes the Slash commands
  router:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: team-up-application-router
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: src/router/router.routerHandler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      Description: Authorizes the request and routes to a slash command lambda.
      Policies:
        # Give lambda permission to get call lambda
        - Statement:
            - Sid: LambdaAllowLambda
              Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - lambda:InvokeFunction
                - lambda:InvokeAsync
              Resource: 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:xxxxxxxxxx:function:team-up-application-slash-command-help'
        # Give Lambda basic execution Permission to the helloFromLambda
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Events:
        HttpPost:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: '/interaction-endpoint-url'
            Method: post

  # This is a Lambda function config associated with the source code: hello-from-lambda.js
  helpSlashCommand:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: team-up-application-slash-command-help
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: src/slash-commands/help.slashCommand
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 60
      Description: Authorizes the request and routes to a slash command lambda.
      Policies:
        # Give Lambda basic execution Permission
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

Comment: Can you not just take one payload for a single lambda and do different things within it based upon the payload parameters?

Comment: @JagrutSharma not with my case. I need to respond within 3 seconds so I have a small routing lambda that's able to spin up quickly and ack the request while invoking another lambda asyncly. The other lambda has all my bots logic and routes the payload, but that codebase has grown and takes about 2-3 seconds to spin up. If I split up the bots logic into individual lambdas I'll be able to keep each one small and contain the larger libraries to lambdas that need them. That way a simple command will spin up quickly because it doesn't need to load all the dependencies for other commands.

Comment: I haven't used this, but see if it helps. Would be good to know if this helped solve your use case: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: @JagrutSharma it looks like the layers are meant to contain libraries that are used by different lambdas. I might setup a layer for each common library used across lambdas in the future. I dont think I can use layers to segment my logic within one lambda application project though. I'll find out more once I start playing around with them